# Как отключить звук в приложении?

Tags: android

Ребята,как отключить звук в приложении именно в фрагменте?
У меня есть фрагмент,в котором я хочу сделать настройки, но данная строчка кода ругается:

```
AudioManager amanager=(AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
```

В Activity не ругается,в фрагменте ругается. Как мне инициализировать AudioManager в Fragment?

Не ругайтесь на меня,если это лёгкая проблема для кого-то,я новичок

Answer (score 1):

Я так понял ругалось на `getSystemService`.
Попробуй через `getActivity()`.  Вот так:

```
 AudioManager amanager=(AudioManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
```

Comment: Спасибо,помогло)